# "send_nav_velocity" function does not work in "guided_set_speed_yaw" example

Tags: dronekit-python

I am new to Ardupilot.
Recently, I am trying to run the example "guided_set_speed_yaw" in dronekit-python api. [here](https://github.com/diydrones/dronekit-python/blob/master/example/guided_set_speed_yaw/guided_set_speed_yaw.py)

Oddly, the "send_nav_velocity" in line 47 does not work (no "Got MAVLink msg" response and nothing happened during real flight tests), while "condition_yaw" in line 67 works.

I am running the script in Odroid U3 with an IRIS quadcopter. The firmware version is V3.3-dev. I basically followed [this website](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/companion-computers/odroid-via-mavlink/) to come to this far.

Maybe it's because of the firmware version? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Solved! I have installed again my firmware with AC3.3 Beta2 and it works! Also, no "Got MAVLink msg" response will pop up for "send_nav_velocity" function, as I thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to the example is https://github.com/diydrones/dronekit-python/blob/master/examples/guided_set_speed_yaw/guided_set_speed_yaw.py (note "examples" not "example"). This is much more "full" version of the example code.

The reason you're not getting a response is that I don't think one is sent - ArduPilot sends a response for COMMAND_LONG messages (as used to send CONDITION_YAW), but not necessarily other message types (as used to send the velocity).